# PHP_EOL troubles in Laravel Seeder

Tags: php, windows, laravel-5.7, laravel-seeding, end-of-line

I tried to run the following lines inside the `run()` function of a Laravel **seeder**.

```
$numbers = <<<EOL
1
2
3
4
EOL;

$array = explode(PHP_EOL, $numbers);
```

After run `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`, I noticed that the `$array` value was:

```
Array (
  0 => '1
2
3
4',
)
```

The expected result was:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
)
```

Why the `explode()` function within a seeder ignores the end of lines?

Comment: It depends entirely on how you generated the line breaks when you wrote the code. If your editor did not use the system `PHP_EOL` then `explode()` won't match them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

works fine

```
$numbers = <<<EOL
1
2
3
4
EOL;

$array = explode("\n", $numbers)
```

The purpose of PHP_EOL is to automatically choose the correct character for the platform. For DOS PHP_EOL - `\r\n`, mac - `\r`, unix - `\n`. In current situation u need to use statically `\n`.

Comment: Did you test it in a seeder?

Comment: @cespon I have just tested this in a Seeder and it works as expected. I think there is something to do with the fact that `PHP_EOL === '\r\n'` whereas that string only has `\n` I will do some digging when I get some time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, **the files that you create with Artisan** (like seeders) **have Unix line endings** (`\n`) while the files created by your editor have DOS line endings probably (`\r\n`).

On Windows, the value of `PHP_EOL` is `\r\n` and the line endings of the seeders are `\n`, so the `explode()` function won't return a expected result.

Options:

- You can use `explode("\n", $numbers)` (using double quotes, not single quotes).
- Or, use `explode(PHP_EOL, $numbers)` and edit the line ending configuration of your editor for the specific file (Sublime Text example below).

[image]